# how to deal with search_as_you_type field and misspelling

Tags: elasticsearch, fuzzy-search, n-gram

I would like to do a search in a e-commerce website to find product with a good query that manage the misspelling.

I was learning elasticsearch and the search_as_you_type field. But in the doc, you have search_as_you_type and fuzziness.

If I have this product :  Post-it Notes 76x76 mm

I would like something  to find this product if I write :

- post-it
- post it
- past it
- post
- it
- ....

and then, find all similar products (because in this example I have only one product but in reality around 30 000)

For the moment I have someting like that for the mapping and I don't know how to add a fuzzyness :

```
"mappings": {
    "properties": {
        "title": {
            "type": "search_as_you_type",
        }
    }
},
```

Thank your for your help

Answer (score 0):

[>Check this Official Document<](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-fuzzy-query.html)

Comment: Yes, I have already used this query, but the search_as_you_type is also really useful to auto_complete the search.